# Prevent direct access to a certain folder/resource without affecting the application flow

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm currently maintaining a website. Our site has a resource which is a .pdf files and a .docx files. Those resources are meant for the internal staff. But recently I found that by searching on google, our resources can be accessed from google.

There's a solution by adding no-index meta tag on the html so that the resources cannot be indexed by google, but I want another layer of protection. I found a solution but I forget where did I get it from. And I have a code like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^.*(pdf|doc|docx)$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(www\.)?eoffice-bkad.kotabogor\.go.id/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(www\.)?view.officeapps.live\.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule . - [R=403,L]
```

That code works, and it return 403 page when accessed if the http referrer is not from the first url.
[image]

But that code is also giving another problem, the code also blocked `<iframe>` tag inside the html
[image]

I'm using Microsoft Office Live preview so that the user can preview the file that they uploaded.

How can I solve this?
Any solutions would gladly be welcomed.

Thank you.

Comment: `http referrer` can be easily changed by user. Seems like you need generic authentication instead. Like [`.htpasswd`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/htpasswd.html)

Comment: "the code also blocked `<iframe>` tag inside the html" - You need to check what `Referer` your server sees. You'll likely need to allow an _empty_ `Referer` header, but that will then allow direct requests and is even easier to circumvent. "adding no-index meta tag on the html" - that obviously only applies to text/html responses. For non-html responses (eg. `.pdf` and `.docx`) you would need to send the corresponding `X-Robots-Tag: noindex` HTTP response header.

Comment: @MrWhite how do I check what ```Referer``` my server sees? And how do I apply the ```X-Robots-Tag: noindex``` on http response header?

Comment: Don't access the true path file directly via address! Create a function to show file for authorized user only. Example: Don't: https://example.com/assets/upload/filename.pdf. Do: https://example.com/file/show/4 <- 4 is fileId in database

Comment: @Doelmi How am I supposed to achieve that if the file is for example .docx? If the file is .pdf perhaps I could use the ```application/pdf``` header. But what about .docx?

Comment: @IchwanulFadhli check this link, list of all mime type http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types